# Why I got very weak signal with my GSM antenna connected to PCB?

Tags: antenna, gsm, pcb-antenna

I have designed the below double sided PCB which uses 3 separate SIM900 modules with separate SIM cards (different operators, same band) and GSM antennas. The PCB is housed inside a plastic enclosure which in turn is housed inside an enclosed steel cabinet. The cabinet also houses some other components like an AC-DC adapter (the type with shielding) and an 20x4 character LCD. There is an AC line running through a hole on the cabinet to the adapter. Cabinet is not connected to common ground.

The antenna pin of each module is connected to an SMD GSM antenna connector via a short trace on the PCB (about  10mm). Each connector is then connected to a commercially available GSM antenna (please see photo and link for specs), running though holes on the steel cabinet and attached (by glue) to the outside of the cabinet.

I am having unstable signals with this design. While on my telephone the signal is full, I am reading from 5% to 60% signal strength on these modules, and it is also kind of fluctuating.

I have seen some commercial SIM900 modules which also run the antenna trace directly to the antenna connector just like my design. But I have also seen some others which use a 1K resistor in series with the antenna trace, and some vias around the trace.

My question is that what should be causing the signal fluctuation, and is there anything I should do to improve the signal quality and stability?

Thank you so much in advance for any experience shared!

External antenna specs: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2dbi-3dbi-gsm-824-960Mhz-1710-1990Mhz-GSM-antenna-SMA-plug-male-connector-Aerial-1-5M/32228127548.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.eIRczU

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I based my design upon the Small Breakout for SIM900 GSM Module by Open Electronics (photo below). Now I can see the only difference is that in their layout, the SMD connector is place as near as possible to the ANT pin of the SIM900 module (I think they are just <1mm apart). Should that be what causes my problem?
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
The (painted) steel cabinet has a lid (also steel) at the back of it. I notice that once I remove the lid (so there is a large opening at the back of the cabinet), the signal strength improves immediately by around 30-40%. And when I put the lid back on the signal drops immediately. So could it be the case that this has something to do with interference?

Comment: Are the antenna inside or outside the steel housing?

Comment: @JonasWielicki The red part is outside the steel housing. Actually the red film can be peeled off, and there is 3M glue to stick it to the outer surface of the steel housing. The entire black cable is inside the steel housing.

Comment: What does the data sheet for the antenna say about sticking it to metal surfaces? A proper data sheet please not the buy-link.

Comment: Are those antenna intended to be used on a metal cabinet? Perhaps try different antenna: the stubby ones with a magnetic base are definitely intended to be placed on a metal cabinet.

Comment: @SteveG this antennas is usually used for cars. It is attached to the roof of the car (which should be metal), and the cable runs to some kind of 3G/GSM box in the car

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks but unfortunately this is a Chinese product and though I've been searching around, no official datasheet is found. I will take note of what you said and try it with some other antennas to see how they fare. So far, I have tried another one with a though-hole bolt to attached to a metal surface to the same effect

Comment: @Dave you may be right, but I'm not convinced by your argument. If I used this antenna in a car I would stick it to the inside of the windscreen. I certainly wouldn't stick to the outside of the car anywhere.

Comment: @Dave - golden rule in EE design = never use a component without a recognizable and plausible data sheet.

Comment: What about the track impedance?? Are you consider the impedance matching? As @Andyaka says never use a component without a datasheet

Comment: Please have a look at my UPDATE 2. Thanks

Comment: If you have the antenna just hanging 300mm from any metal does it offer a decent signal.  If so then sticking it to a metal surface is causing part of your problem.  I have seen numerous GSM antennas (probably made for and) used on metal cabinets but they tend to be NOT-flat.  These flat antennas may be intended for sticking to plastic or glass.

Comment: Also keep the three antennas as far from each other as possible.  They WILL interfere with operation occasionally even if only one is in active use, heartbeats and negotiations occur sporadically on idle connections.

Comment: Also make sure the antennas are for the correct band.  If you have a spare one you can crack it open and measure/inspect the elements.  If it is a single band antenna and you are using modules in quad band mode it will have horrible performance when it is connected at the other main band.

Comment: @KalleMP the flat antenna has the correct band. I found that hanging it 100mm from the steel box gives the module full signal. So I think the metal surface is the main problem. PCB layout is flawed but i think its not the main issue. For aesthetic requirements, still can't figure out how to mount the antenna

Answer (score 3):

I was going to say "check the power supply", since those things have very spiky current draw and demand proper decoupling and low ripple. They might also be subject to crosstalk through the ground plane.

Do you get better results if you only power up one of the modules?

However, the fact that taking the back off the Faraday cage improves reception greatly suggests that the antennas are doing very little work. If you've stuck the antennas to the metal surface, they're probably too close to it to be able to work properly. Normally you want antennas perpendicular to the ground plane.

What sort of signal strength do you get with the lid on and same antenna, but hanging the antenna in free space > 30cm from the box?

Is the box grounded? To the same ground as the PCB?

Are the track impedances correct? Do you need a cutout in the ground plane around the SMA connector?

Comment: yes, I have been doing research and what you say is right, I think its the power supply. well antenna should be doing very little work because most of the time the GSM module is idle. I have tried grounding the box (PCB GND) and signal improves a little. I will try other things you suggest and I believe you are pointing me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I have done some experiment with antenna attached and not attached to the steel box. This time, I solder a second test PCB which performs a little better. With back lid closed and all antenna attached, the left & right modules report a signal of about 70% while the middle one just 0%-30%. When I move the antennas 5cm from the box, the left & right modules got full signal white the middle one got 70%. So while I am sure there are still issues with the PCB layout, the problem lies more in the part of antennas. Would you have any further comments/advice?

Comment: Antenna design isn't really my area, but when I used GSM antennas they came with datasheets specifying the minimum distance to a ground plane. I suspect you'd get better results with "stubby" antennas, positioned as far apart as possible and perpendicular to the plane of the box.